# c# mongodb System.MissingMethodException: void System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, mongodb

trying to use the mongodb in one of my c# projects, using the example off their docs to test everything but I keep getting this odd error

```
error! MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.MissingMethodException: void System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes..ctor(string,byte[],int,System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName)
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.ScramShaAuthenticator+ClientFirst.Transition (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator+SaslConversation conversation, System.Byte[] bytesReceivedFromServer) [0x000da] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.Transition (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator+SaslConversation conversation, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator+ISaslStep currentStep, MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument result, MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument& command) [0x00038] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.Authenticate (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IConnection connection, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionDescription description, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008c] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.DefaultAuthenticator.Authenticate (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IConnection connection, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionDescription description, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009c] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.Authenticate (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IConnection connection, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionDescription description, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] authenticators, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00040] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.Authenticate (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IConnection connection, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionDescription description, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00025] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003b] in <aa6b841a807344eea7c91441c9eace83>:0
                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1[TDocument].Execute (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00031] in <de98c2ec1446409986bc8acf49d23a01>:0
                             at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.MongoQueryableImpl`2[TInput,TOutput].GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <de98c2ec1446409986bc8acf49d23a01>:0
                             at StaffUtils.Features.Database.DatabaseConnectionTest () [0x0003c] in <01495ab2108f41f29b96324db58e8300>:0
```

Not sure whats going on, I have all the required refs and reinstall multiple times w restarting VS and even tried using a lower version, Tried making another project from scratch with barebone testing stuff and got the same thing, Doubt its an issue with my code but this is what im using

```cs
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(uri);
var client = new MongoClient(uri);
var db = client.GetDatabase("PlayerData");
var coll = db.GetCollection<PlayerData>("data");
var cursor = coll.AsQueryable();

                foreach (var document in cursor)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(document);
                }
```

Comment: which OS? target framework? platform?

Comment: also please provide a full stacktrace

Comment: using windows 10, .net is 1.7.2, heres the full stack: https://pastebin.com/sve27NtB
also just for reference, im developing a this as a plugin for a dedicated game server

Comment: are you sure that .net 1.7.2?

Comment: also, add a stacktrace (ie full error message) to the question

Comment: oh my bad, I meant 4.7.2

Comment: made a console app and it worked, so I think im missing a ref